# Minecraft Dungeons local co-op is broken with Remote Play

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, minecraft-dungeons

Picture this scenario:

I have 2 Xbox One controllers. A friend is coming over to play local Minecraft Dungeons co-op, however both of the two controllers are occupied. The friend brings over a PS3 controller, specifically the Sixaxis. To connect the Sixaxis to the Xbox One, I set up a Sixaxis to Xbox 360 controller emulator on a laptop, then start a Remote play session so the Sixaxis can be used on the Xbox.

This all functions as intended, with all three controllers being able to navigate the UI. However, upon launching Minecraft Dungeons, only two controllers can connect.

P1 is the Xbox One controller. If I try to connect P2 as the other Xbox One controller, then the Sixaxis cannot join as P3. If I connect the Sixaxis as P2, then the other Xbox One controller cannot connect as P3.

The way I see it, there are two possible causes for this:

A: The fact that one controller is connecting by Remote Play disallows any others from joining

B: The fact that the emulated controller is an Xbox 360 controller (I do not think this is the case, as the Xbox app should be accepting XInput, so there should be no difference.)

How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit:**

I am using DsHidMini in Ds4Windows mode, with Ds4Windows in XInput mode. The Xbox is an Xbox One S, while the computer is running Windows 11 Home. I am using the Xbox app for streaming.

This is what it looks like with both Xbox Controllers connected as P1 and P2, as well as the Xbox 360 (Emulated):

[image: Local Co-op Player Screen]

As You Can See, there is no "Add Controller." The same thing happens when the Sixaxis connects, except the other Xbox One controller does not work.

Comment: Is this "streaming" the Remote Play? Btw, is it possible that P2 and the remote P3 were actually controlling the same user? This could explain why only one of them was able to join.

Comment: Yes, sorry. "Streaming" is the Xbox Remote Play feature. There are three different  users logged in: P1's account, P2's account and P2's guest. When joining the game, the xbox controller joins P2 as P2's account, while the Sixaxis joins P2 as the guest account, however adding the additional controller does not work. It does not even show the "hold l2 to join" dialog.

Comment: @pinckerman They are not controlling the same user. Does using a guest account modify anything?

Comment: This makes me feel nostalgic for the days when we had to MacGyver these kinds of solutions. It was the foundation of my mates and my careers in IT.